# How to copy content type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, 2019

I have a custom content type on our site which is used on a list. I now need to create another content type that is nearly identical to the first. Rather than build the content type manually, I thought I would just copy the first one and then make changes to the copy.

However, upon looking for it, I can't find anything similar to the "Save as Template" feature that lists & sites have, or the "Create from..." option you get for views.

**Is anyone familiar with how to duplicate an existing content type into a new content type?**

---

More Info:

- SP2019 Enterprise On-Premises
- I have full access to server & Powershell
- Source list & destination list are both on the same site collection & subsite.

Comment: If you have PowerShell Available, you can use PNP PowerShell to export the content type to XML and then Import it. (https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/02/sharepoint-online-export-import-content-type-using-powershell.html) Ad. for the future you should consider using Content Type Hub (no, it's not Site HUB) where you build your content type and can distribute it everywhere in the SharePoint Sites.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Why do you need another content type if they are in the same site/subsite - just use the same content type in both lists
2. If there is a need for a new content type - create a new content type and set it's parent to be the first content type. This will make sure that the second content type has all the fields and settings from the first one. Then you can modify the later to meet your needs.
3. Use PnP Powershell to export the content type schema XML and import this XML schema to create a new content type- here is a reference - https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/03/export-import-content-type-using-powershell.html

Comment: I'll try #2 and see if that works. As for the why, they want some minor customizations to the content type's fields, but without changing the existing one.